# How can i write SQL search name?

Tags: sql

how can i write SQL to search name in database? Example name : Brul Nol
Note: I can search Brul Nol or Nol Brul and then i get the same result

Comment: You need to add more details like which database flavor you use, and you table's structure

Answer (score 2):

I would use the LIKE keyword.

For this query, I would use:

```
SELECT name
FROM database
WHERE name LIKE '%Brul%'
AND name LIKE '%Nol%';
```

The % wildcard on both sides of the word searches the name column for any name with Brul and Nol in it, so this would return names Brul Nol and Nol Brul.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE '%SearchWord%'
```

This gives all the name where your search word appear in any position of the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fulltext search](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php) technique (If you use Mysql).

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(first_name, last_name) AGAINST('Brul Nol' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

To perform fulltext search you need to add FTS index firstly,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT index_name(first_name, last_name);
```

Comment: I don't think this is standard SQL, and he hasn't said he is using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using LIKE operator, like wise
For search

select Name from TABLE_NAME where Name like 'Brul%'
[Finds any values that starts with "Brul"]

select Name from TABLE_NAME where Name like '%nol'
[Finds any values that ends with "nol"]

select Name from TABLE_NAME where Name like 'Brul%nol'
[Finds any values that starts with "Brul" and ends with "nol"]